# Path of asset in CSS

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have a css file and an image in a bundle directory according these paths:

```
My_project
+-src
 +-Project
  +-MyBundle
   +-Resources
    +-public
     +-css
      +-MyCSSfile.css
     +-images
      +-MyImage.jpeg
```

In my view I call my css using assetic:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/myBundle/css/MyCSSfile.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

In my CSS I use:

```
background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
```

Obviously it doens't work. The url which is returned by symfony is:
"http://localhost:8888/MY_Project/web/bundles/myBundle/css/bundles/myBundle/images/background.jpg".

Any idea? Please

Comment: Look a little closer at this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets

Comment: I did. Looking at the documentation is always the first thing I do. That's why I refer to the CSS files using their actual, publicly-accessible path.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, maybe you should use :

```
php app/console assets:install
```

in order to copy or symlink assets in the web/bundles directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php bin/console assetic:dump
```

and try also to clear your cache